# Azure Application_End not hit and Application_Start hits multiple times (a few minutes in between)

Tags: .net, azure, global-asax, application-start

In my Azure environment I have a webrole with on the instances multiple websites. The Application_Start() method in global.asax in a WCF-project is called multiple times (a few minutes in between), without the Application_End or Application_Error being hit. In the Emulator I don’t have this issue.

In the eventlog I see a WAS-event: “The application '/' belonging to site 'xxxx' has an invalid AppPoolId 'xxxxx’ set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored” (and the site will be disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid.) that is logged once 1.5 hour.

Anyone’s got an idea what’s going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735307(v=ws.10).aspx

Most likely you have some of these things set for multiple sites.  If you can remote into the Azure instance, you should be able to check and then make the proper adjustment.